# TinyMCE 4: Get text area content to send with Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, tinymce

I'm making some tests trying to get the content of a `textarea` rendered by  `TinyMCE 4` to send it in a `post request` through `Axios` but I cannot do it.

I tried with `document.getElementById` and `tinymce.get('mytextarea')` but none of those works.

- With `document.getElementById` returns an empty string
- With `tinymce.get('mytextarea')` returns null

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Two Forms</title>
    <script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script>
  let editor = tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea',
  });
   //Line to test if get function works. But it dosen't work console excepction
   //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of null
   tinymce.get('mytextarea').setContent('Hello');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <textarea id="mytextarea" name="body"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="input" value="POST">
        <button onclick="send()" type="button">GET</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-DZqqY3PiOvTP9HkjIWgjO6ouCbq+dxqWoJZ/Q+zPYNHmlnI2dQnbJ5bxAHpAMw+LXRm4D72EIRXzvcHQtE8/VQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Trying to get the text area value but it dosen't work neither. returns an empty string
        //let  body = document.getElementById('mytextarea').value;

        //Try to  get  the text area content to store in body variable, returns null
        let body = tinymce.get('mytextarea');
        function send() {
            console.log('The Body: ' + body);   
            axios.post('/post.php', {
              body: body
            })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
            }, (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `post.php`  only have this content to process the requests.

```
<?php

//Takes the post from the form.
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {

    echo "POST " . $_POST['body'];

} else {

    // Takes raw data from the request
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // Converts it into a PHP object
    $data = json_decode($json);

    var_dump($data->body);
}
```

Note: Only for testing purpose I'm using 2 buttons, the `input` to send the form  normally and the `button` to send the post through `Axios`

Comment: I believe you should do either `form action="post.php"` or `button onclick="send()"`. You are currently doing both. In `send()` you should add `send(event){ event.preventDefault();` otherwise, submitting the form will automatically reload the page (which is the default, and quite dumb, behaviour). Other than that, I don't know

Comment: it's only for testing purpose, ignore the input type submit  and the form post, focus on button and send function. My problem is that i cannot get the textarea content to store it in a var :-(

Answer (score 1):

When you load TinyMCE you overlay the original `textarea` with an `iframe`. If you don't use the native form submission process you need to manually either...

- Extract the data from TinyMCE using the `getContent()` API
- Get TinyMCE to update the `textarea` via the `triggerSave()` API

Before you call your `send()`function simply calling something like:

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
```

...should cause TinyMCE to update the underlying `textarea`.

***Note:**  In your current code you call `let body = tinymce.get('mytextarea');`.  This simply assigns the `body` variable a reference to the TinyMCE object in the browser but not the content of the editor. That would need something like `let body = tinymce.get('mytextarea').getContent();`.*